# C# What is the least CPU intensive way to know when a new process has been created?

Tags: c#, c++, events, memory, process

My program does things when specific processes are created by third party applications.

When I use `ManagementEventWatcher` to watch for `Win32_ProcessStartTrace`. 
The event doesn't show up until two seconds after a process has started which is much too slow.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` requires continuous polling which 
increases cpu usage when you try to lower the delay between calls.

I was thinking about using a global windows hook that would inject my C++ dll into every newly created process and send an event to my program from within the created process. However I'd like to avoid that if possible since it seems like overkill.

In C#, how can I get an instant event when a new process is created without killing my CPU to do it?

Comment: The least CPU intensive way is to have the OS notify your program when a process is created.  This could be an event message or you may *hook* a function into an existing vector.  There are no methods in *standard* C++, as this issue is in the Operating System domain (not all OS support this feature).

Comment: I feel like this calls for the Speed rant, so I will just link it: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ But the hooks seem to be the way. Basically they are low level event-like things that have Windows tell your code about something happening. Unfortunately they require to pass over into umanaged code.

Comment: I know only one kind of process that would do anything like that and thus might be a good starting point: Any Virus Scanner. Any background scanner has to hook into the Windows read and write routines to do it's job when files are written or read. Depending on what the process do, there might be other ways to detect them. Like, are they started as Services? Do they use Network communication?